# Poignant story of forgetting ... feels like Ellison

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Short story: A man arrives in an isolated room, in shock of some sort brought on by his travel there. Temporary amnesia. There's someone else (AI/machine/hologram) already there, also not remembering who he himself is. 
The traveler eventually overcomes the shock of his transit, and is back on his journey in a snap, leaving behind the degraded AI trying desperately to remember its self/soul.

The story closed with several sentences indicating the loss of self, each without the direct object no longer remembered. "I need ...". "I love ...".

Ironically, I've forgotten the source of the story myself :-) Been trying to recall it for some time. Feels like Ellison, for what it's worth.

Comment: I'm sure I've read this, which means it's in my book collection somewhere, but I cannot put my finger on it. Are there any other details you can remember that might help to trigger my memory? Even the slightest detail could help.

Comment: I wish I could think of more, @JohnRennie ... I'll try. I suspect it's in my collection somewhere as well, but half of it's boxed right now.